# Ordering of objects in java

Tags: java

is there any way to sort the objects in java. I dont want to implement comparable interface or any other sorting algorithms.

Comment: how then do you wish to sort your objects??? You either write your own or you use what is there.

Comment: Then on what basis you want to sort objects without comparing

Comment: reinventing the wheel for its own sake is not a smart idea...

Comment: Collections.shuffle will sort the objects without any notion of comparison or ordering.

Comment: Well, simply said, if you don't implement `Comparable`, you won't be able to sort/order your objects.

Comment: @roshanK how do you exactly want to sort then, do you have some predefined order? and sort according to that?

Comment: Why are you not willing to implement the comparable  ? Any specific reasons ?

Comment: @Babar T. my guess would be either a lack of understanding or a lack of effort in learning to program.

Comment: @Jeff Collections.shuffle randomly permutes the specified list. But can it called sorting of the objects. It cannot guarantee the same order again

Comment: @GustlyWind: I think Jeff was telling a joke. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot sort things without (at least) *using* a sorting algorithm.

You also can't sort *arbitrary* objects, since Java provides no reliable ordering that will work for arbitrary objects.  (See below.)

However, if your objects are instances of classes that support `Comparable` ... or you can implement a `Comparator`, then you *can* sort them, using:

```
   Arrays.sort<T>(T[], Comparator<T>)
```

or

```
   Arrays.sort<T extends Comparable>(T[])
```

In short, you have to implement `Comparable` or provide a `Comparator`.  But if you do, the Java class library provides a good general-purpose sort algorithm that you can use.

---

The two obvious approaches for comparing incomparable objects won't work:

- You could compare the results of their `toString()` methods.  However, there's no guarantee that

  ```
  a.toString().equals(b.toString())  IMPLIES  a.equals(b)
  ```
- You could compare their hashCodes, or their identity hashCodes, but hashcode equality does not imply object equality either.

It is theoretically possible to use reflection to access all of an object's fields, extract their values and compare them in some predictable sequence to give an ordering.  This might work, but you'd end up with an ordering that was expensive to compute, that didn't make much sense, and was (if you weren't careful) inconsistent with `equals(Object)`.  So this sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: I believe the OP meant that he didn't want to implement the sorting *machinery* (quick sort, bubble sort, etc...). I would *presume* that he's willing to implement the *comparison* logic... I hope...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know the answer would blossom so much (you still got an up-vote from me). :)

Comment: It's not true that you can't define a stable sort ordering for arbitrary Java objects. [Here's proof](https://code.google.com/p/dellroad-stuff/source/browse/trunk/src/java/org/dellroad/stuff/java/ObjectComparator.java).

Answer (score 3):

Sorting a collection of objects which don't themselves implement comparable can be achieved like this (assuming MyObject is the object you want to compare and sort):

```
List<MyObject> myList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

// add MyObject instances to the list

Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<MyObject>()
    {

        @Override
        public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2)
        {
            // perform your custom comparison of the two objects
            // and return the result
        }
    })
```

But without any Comparator or Comparable implementation there's obviously no way you could sort a collection of objects.

Answer (score 1):

Sort objects without a sorting algorithm? Hardly. In no language. What I am missing in your question is: "I want to avoid strict ordering criteria."

Answer (score 1):

Code sample from java [tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html). This sample code doesn't implement sorting algorithm, what it is doing is that it is telling the Sort algorithm which field to sort the objects on. Since there can be many fields in an object this part is required.

```
import java.util.*;
public class EmpSort {
    static final Comparator<Employee> SENIORITY_ORDER =
                                 new Comparator<Employee>() {
        public int compare(Employee e1, Employee e2) {
            return e2.hireDate().compareTo(e1.hireDate());
        }
    };

    // Employee database
    static final Collection<Employee> employees = ... ;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Employee>e = new ArrayList<Employee>(employees);
        Collections.sort(e, SENIORITY_ORDER);
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

The code sample [here](http://www.javadeveloper.co.in/java-example/java-comparator-example.html) shows how same object collection sorted in different orders based on different fields.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, ensure correct position when insertion, something like balanced-tree. Comparing is inevitable.